# inputmask dynamic mask change on last digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I want to use [Jquery.Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) to mask a phone number input and I'm dong it as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new {@class = "form-control mask-phone"})
```

and in my JS I initialize it:

```
$(".mask-phone").inputmask({
    mask: "(99)9{4,5}-9999}",
    greedy: false
});
```

and it works great, but the dynamic input is triggered right after the sixth digit and i have to manually put the caret after the hyphen. Is there a way to only trigger the dynamics in the mask after the very last digit has been typed?

I'm not sure I made myself clear. I short terms, I want a mask that goes from:

`(99)9999-9999`

to:

`(99)99999-9999`

without having to drag the caret after typing the sixth digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 years after: the solution for this case is now in the Input mask documentation, under '[keepStatic](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/#keepstatic)' option. So in this case you could do somthing like this:

```
$(".mask-phone").inputmask({
    mask: ["(99)9{4}-9999", "(99)9{5}-9999"],
    keepStatic: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using, it works pretty well

```
$(".mask-telefone").on("keydown change", function() {
    if ($(this).val().replace(/[_\-()]/g,"").length >= 10){
        $(this).inputmask("(99)99999-9999");

    else {
        $(this).inputmask("(99)9999-9999");
    }
});
```